putting a try-catch block fixed compilation error in program
I wanted to read from a file using the Scanner class and when i implemented it it keeps throwing File-not-found exception but i checked multiple times with a couple of methods listed in the code and even made another file to read from and from different parts of the directory and still the same error was thrown but just as a put a try-catch block around the declaration of the Scanner object the program compiled and run without any errors
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class App extends EmployeeManagementSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("/home/rayan/Documents/Assignment2/input2.txt");
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        System.out.println(inputFile.exists());
        System.out.println(outputFile.exists());
        System.out.println(inputFile.canRead());
        System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputFile);        
    }
}


i tried placing the file in different locations and checking whether it was readable and also tried using the absolute path. I was expecting it to compile and the Scanner object to work

Catching the exception means you are just eating that error, checkout this https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/amp/
